# When I am Trying To load Json data from local file using futurebuilder in flutter it Shows a error type Null is Not a subtype of String

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'dart:math';

import "dart:async";

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quizapp/style.dart'; 
class loadjson extends StatelessWidget {
  String Name  = ""; 
  loadjson(this.Name);  
  String assetload = "";
  setasset(){
    if(Name == "Python"){
      assetload = "assets/python.json";
    } 
    else if(Name == "Java"){
      assetload = "assets/java.json";
    } 
    else if(Name == "C++"){ 
      assetload = "assets/cpp.json";

    }  
    else if(Name == "C"){ 
      assetload = "assets/c.json";

    }  
    else if(Name == "Javascript"){ 
      assetload = "assets/js.json";

    }   
    else if(Name == "Linux"){ 
      assetload = "assets/linux.json";

    }   
    else{
      assetload = "assets/aws.json";
    }


  }
   

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    setasset(); 
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(assetload, cache: false), 
      builder: (context, snapshot){ 
        List mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString()); 
       
        // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
        if(mydata == null){
          return Scaffold(
             body: Center(
              child: Text("Loading....",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Sweet Husky ", fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 20.0),),
             ),
             
          );
          
        } 
        else{  
          return quiz(mydata: mydata);  
           
          
          
          
          
        } 
        
      },
    );

    
  }
} 

class quiz extends StatefulWidget {
   final List mydata;
  const quiz({Key? key, required this.mydata}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: no_logic_in_create_state
  State<quiz> createState() => _quizState(mydata);
}

class _quizState extends State<quiz> {
   final List mydata; 
  _quizState(this.mydata);  
  Color Colortoshow = Apppstyle.acent; 
  Color right = Apppstyle.right;  
  Color wrong = Apppstyle.wrong; 
  int marks = 0; 
  bool disableAnswer = false; 
  int j = 1;  
  int i =0;
  int timer  = 30; 
  String Showtimer = "30"; 
  var random_array; 
  Map<String, Color> btncolor = {
     "a": Apppstyle.acent,  
     "b": Apppstyle.acent,  
     "c": Apppstyle.acent, 
     "d": Apppstyle.acent

  };  
  @override
  void initState() { 
    Startimer(); 
    genrandomarray(); 
    
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }  
 
  
   bool canceltime = false;  
    genrandomarray(){
      var distinids = []; 
      var rand = new Random(); 
     for(int i =0; ;){
       distinids.add(rand.nextInt(10)); 
       random_array = distinids.toSet().toList(); 
       if(random_array.length < 10){
         continue;
       } 
       else{
         break;
       } 
       
       
      } 
      print(random_array);
    }  
    

    void Startimer() async{
      const onsec = Duration(seconds: 1);  
      Timer.periodic(onsec, (Timer T) { 
        setState(() {
          if(timer < 1){
             T.cancel(); 
             nextquestion(); 

          }
          else if(canceltime == true){
            timer = timer - 1; 

          }
          Showtimer = timer.toString();
        });
      });
      
    } 
    void nextquestion(){
      canceltime = false; 
      timer  = 30; 
      setState(() {
        if(j < 10){
          i = random_array[i]; 
          j++; 

        }
        else{
          btncolor["a"] = Apppstyle.acent;  
          btncolor["b"] = Apppstyle.acent;  
          btncolor["c"] = Apppstyle.acent;  
          btncolor["d"] = Apppstyle.acent; 
          disableAnswer = false; 
          Startimer();
        }
      });
    }
    void Checkanswer(String K){
      if(mydata[2][i.toString()] == mydata[1][i.toString()][K]){
        marks = marks+5; 
        Colortoshow = right; 

      } 
      else{ 
        Colortoshow = wrong;

      } 
      setState(() {
        btncolor[K] = Colortoshow; 
        canceltime = true; 
        disableAnswer = false; 

      }); 
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), nextquestion);
    }  
    @override 
    void setState(fn){
      if(mounted){
        super.setState(() {
          fn;
        });
      }
    }
    Widget Choicebutton(String K){
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0), 
        child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed:() => Checkanswer(K), 
          color:btncolor[K],
          child: Text(mydata[i][i.toString()][K], style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Eriega", fontSize: 18.0), maxLines: 1,), 
          minWidth: 200.0, 
          height: 45.0, 
          splashColor: Apppstyle.splash, 
          highlightColor: Apppstyle.splash, 
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
        ),
      );
    }  
    
     
   



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
    return WillPopScope( 
      onWillPop:() async => false,
         
      
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column( 
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 3, 
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0), 
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft, 
                child: Text(mydata[0][i.toString()],style:  TextStyle(fontFamily: " Eriega", fontSize: 16.0),),
              ),
            ), 
            Expanded(
              flex:6, 
              child: AbsorbPointer(
                absorbing: disableAnswer, 
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
                  children: [
                    Choicebutton('a'),  
                    Choicebutton('b'), 
                    Choicebutton('c'), 
                    Choicebutton('d'),

                  ],
                ),
              ),
              
            ) 

          ],
             

        ),
      )

    );
  
    
  }
}
```

**and the code For  Appstyle class**

```
import 'package:flutter/Material.dart';

    class Apppstyle{
      static Color cardColor = Color(0xFF80DEEA); 
      static Color right = Color(0xFF2E7D32); 
      static Color wrong = Color(0xFFF44336); 
      static Color acent =  Color(0xFF18FFFF); 
      static Color splash = Color(0xFF4DD0E1);
    } 
  Error Shown while building   
     type 'Null' is not a subtype of 'String' 
     The relevant error-causing widget was quiz
```

I am building a multipage quiz App using json file stored locally
but when I try to load json file using futurebuilder in flutter
It  Shows error while  type Null is not a subtype of Type String
The relevant error-causing widget was quiz i am trying to display the json data when the
user tab a Inkwell

Comment: read carefully `FutureBuilder` official docs - they have an example how to use `FutureBuilder` the right way

Comment: Typically there should be line number with the error. And if you would remove all code not related to the issue  it would become much easier for someone else to understand the code